# Torch Backpropagation Problem Behavior Cloning IRL

Tags: gradient, reinforcement-learning, torch, ray

I'm implementing the Inverse Reinforcement Learning (IRL) algorithm described in the [BCIRL](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.16194.pdf) research paper link to the paper. Specifically, I'm using the Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) variant to learn the reward function for a biped robot.

The algorithm follows these steps:

```
Set Ksi to some initial values.
Create a reward function that depends on Ksi as a hyperparameter.
Train the agent with this reward function to obtain a policy.
Evaluate the policy by calculating the loss between the predicted actions and expert actions (from another agent we aim to copy).
Backpropagate the loss to update the Ksi values.
Repeat steps 2-5.
```

I'm using Ray's RLlib and Torch for my agent's policy, but after training, the policy weights seem to be independent of the Ksi values. I specified requires_grad for the Ksi parameters to enable backpropagation through the reward function.

Is there a way to ensure that the policy weights (requires_grad) remain dependent on the Ksi values so that the reward function returns gradients that can be backpropagated?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expected that when I try to call :

```
train_agent.get_policy().get_weights()
```

I was going to get tensors that requires grad, instead I get what seems like numpy arrays.

Comment: Do provide more information and better yet the code around that area of trouble.